# Xterm: How can I direct input from one terminal tab to another?

Tags: linux, macos, unix, terminal

As I am a beginner coder, I apologize in advance for improper terminology.
This is the main script which calls the script ping.sh in a new tab.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    echo "The script is running!"

    rm ping.txt

    echo "Enter your desired IP address:"

    read ADDRESS

            osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell application "Terminal"
            do script "./ping.sh"
            end tell'

    echo "The script has ended!"

    exit 0;
```

So, as I said the script ping.sh is called now. It goes like this.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    echo "Welcome to the new tab!"

    ping -c 3 $ADDRESS > ping.txt

    exit 0
```

The problem I have is that the read input from the first tab isn't recognizable in the second tab. Is there a way to solve this? I am probably missing a linking constructor or something like that. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what `osascript` is, or how it works, but it might be helpful to know that shell scripts can access command line arguments with the special variables `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc.

This means you can rewrite your `ping.sh` script like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Welcome to the new tab!"

ping -c 3 "$1" > ping.txt

exit 0
```

And then call it like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter your desired IP address:"

read ADDRESS

./ping.sh "$ADDRESS"
```

Otherwise, to make sure subsequent commands have access to the same environment variables, you have to `export` them. From `help export`:

> export: export [-fn] [name[=value] ...] or export -p
>
> Set export attribute for shell variables.
>
> Marks each NAME for automatic export to the environment of subsequently
> executed commands.  If VALUE is supplied, assign VALUE before exporting.

To make your *original* `ping.sh` work you could do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter your desired IP address:"

read ADDRESS
export ADDRESS

./ping.sh
```